# How to add transmission fluid with no dipstick?

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission

I have a 2003 chevy cavalier, and just replaced the radiator due to a transmission fluid leak into the antifreeze. I don't know how much fluid was lost because the transmission was designed without a dipstick. The car seems to drive fine so far. I have also heard that adding too much fluid can damage an automatic transmission.

How can I tell if I need to add fluid, and how much fluid, to an automatic transmission with no dipstick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the passenger side of the transmission there is a removable plug. The method used to determine fluid level is similar to checking differential or manual transmission fluid. If fluid leaks out of the hole with the plug removed the fluid is at the proper level. This requires the vehicle to be level, not an easy task considering you may have to jack up the car and remove the tire if you don't have a lift. There are several you tube videos of modifications to make this task easier.

Comment: Will I need to lift the car to find this plug? I tried looking, but I can't really get under the car to identify anything.

Comment: I found a video that showed how to find the plug, have to remove the tire like you said.